# Layout does not reflow when transition canvas parent's margin-right with react-spring and react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring, react-three-fiber

I am trying to create an animation with @react-spring, a mesh defined into a canvas with r3f and some dom elements.
Actually I am unable to correctly change canvas size when I change margin-right of parent container. It does not reflow the layout, because if I scroll or change window dimension it works. Also, if I remove the canvas element and put in a dom element, all work as expected.

To give you an idea I prepared this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bohr-lqxo7

Can I fix it some ways?

I am open to all kind of suggestions: switch from margin-right to something else (width, transform and so on) or with something different pattern.

For example, I already tried transitioning `width` property instead of `margin-right`, but the model moves to the new size of canvas ungraceful. You can also test it if you change `useSpring` stuff into `BigWrapperModel` component (you need just to comment and uncomment, it is already here).

Thanks!

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden` to `Canvas` parent container seems to fix issue with `margin-right`, but still model moves to the new size of canvas ungraceful. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from `margin-right` to `right` and add `position: absolute` to `container-globe`. I also added `hidden: overflow` to `wrapper-big-globe`.

It seeems to work, containers now transition to the new size and position; model moves properly. Just check original codesandbox for a fix working example.